# Is there something like USN Journal on Linux filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inotify

I often use Everything (a search tool) on Windows. It uses [USN Journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal) to speed file name search.

Do Linux filesystems (ext4, xfs, btrfs, etc.) have a similar function to USN Journal?

Answer (score 2):

The [USN journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal) lets a Windows program keep track of changes to files.

An program on Linux can do the same by using [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).  It allows a program to be notified about every change to the files.

It is not a function of any particular filesystem, but of the kernel's filesystem layer, so it works with any filesystem.

Comment: "inotify acts to extend filesystems to notice changes to the filesystem, and report those changes to applications." I don't think it can be used to search files.

Comment: @ibear Keep a record of files in a directory, and then perform quick search based on theses records. You should have read the link provided more carefully.

Comment: Inotify isn't really the same thing - there is a limit to the recursion so you cannot really monitor many subdirs easily.